# Hyperplane sections on projective surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, intersection-theory

I am studying Beauville's book "Complex Algebraic Surfaces".
At page 2 he defines the intersection form (.) on the Picard group of a surface.
For $L, L^\prime \in Pic(S)$

$$(L.L^\prime)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_S)-\chi(L^{-1})-\chi(L^{\prime-1})+\chi(L^{-1}\otimes L^{\prime-1})$$

Why the self-intersection (i.e $(H.H)=H^2$) of an hyperplane section $H$ on $S$ is always positive?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please consider using LaTeX to typeset your mathematics and make them easier for everyone to read: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This self-intersection is exactly the degree of $S$.

Concretely, choose $H$ and $H'$ in general position, then $S \cap H$ and $S \cap H'$ are two curves on $S$, and they intersect in some number of points.  This 
already shows that the intersection is non-negative.  The fact that it is positive
is a general fact about projective varieties: projective varieities of complementary dimension always have a *positive* number of intersection points.
(Apply this to $S$, which is of dimension $2$, and $H \cap H'$, which is a linear subspace of codimension $2$, i.e. of complementary dimension to $S$.)

Comment: thank you. However this is not completely clear to me since on a surface i can find curves C with $C^2=-1$.

Comment: Dear itioteca, Yes, but those curves don't move in families (otherwise you could move the curve off itself before computing the intersection, and then the intersection would necessarily be non-negative). In other words: a necessary condition for negative self-intersection is that the curve not admit any non-infinitesimal embedded deformations in $S$.  In particular, its linear equivalence class should be a singleton (i.e. just the curve itself).   Hyperplane sections, on the other hand, obviously admit lots of deformations!  In any case, as I wrote, the intersection of $S$ with a linear ...

Comment: ... subspace of codimension $2$ (which computes $H^2$) is positive (see Thm. 7.2 of Ch. I of Hartshorne).   So ... what isn't clear?  Regards,

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you.